# Graph in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-tablelayout, android-graphview

I want to implement a graph as below for each item of a listview. 
[image: cell graph]

The cell will turn green or red based upon the input.
The number of coloured cells will increase based upon the input.
Could you please tell me what would be the best approach in attaining the same. Right now I have used table view to achieve this. But the list view is very slow. Tried searching for some third party graph libraries but had no luck.

Thank You.

Comment: Is the number of uncolored cells fixed? This will be important for the solving strategy

Comment: @ThomasRichter Yes. the number of cells are fixed. Only the colour changes, depending on the input.

Comment: I have written an answer. I would suggest you to make a costum view. I have done that for similar problems like a progress graph. It's relatively easy to make and you can customize it very fast, which increase the reusability. Feel free to ask me more about that, if you don't get something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a fixed number of cells, you could define a **custom view**.
Inside the custom view, you can then define a **canvas**, where you can draw colored rectangles. Just provide some kind of **update** method for your custom view, to keep the canvas refreshing whenever there's a data change.
The advantage of this solution:
 + It's faster than hiding / showing and inflating views
 + You can custimze it much faster
 + You have all functions you need in one class
 And it's relatively easy to accomplish, have a look at the android developer page for this topic: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Richter.